# How to Render component many times in react js on input value

Tags: reactjs, function, loops, jsx

Problem: How to Render component many times, when i give input value in input box (Eg : If i enter 5 in input box Hello World Should render 5 times

React Interview Question .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight-forward and there are *loads* of ways about going about this.

Here's just one: `new Array(number).fill(<Component />)`

As with any of possibilities, you the developer, will have to justify various decisions.

- I have opted to `fill` a `new Array(n)` of length `n`.
- I would need some kind of error checking to stop users entering dumb values (`""` would be such a value)

Other error: checking

- `min` - guard against negative values (perhaps `max` would also be logical)
- `step` - guard against decimal values (how could one get 2.5 elements after all?!)
- `type="number"` - guarding against unparsable inputs like strings

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Component = () => {
  return <div>Hello World</div>
}

const Example = () => {
    const [howMany, setHowMany] = useState(1);
    
    const allComponents = new Array(howMany).fill(<Component />)
  
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="number" step={1} min={0} value={howMany} onChange={(event) => {
          const newValue = event.target.value
          const parsedValue = parseInt(newValue)
          if (parsedValue < 0 || isNaN(parsedValue)) {
            console.warn("Cannot set");
            // Do some error handling
            return 
          }
          console.log("setting", parsedValue)
          setHowMany(parsedValue)
        }} />
        <div>
          {allComponents.map((elem, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              {elem}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```